# DataGridView.DataMember throws error when assigned a two-part name. i.e. Sales.StoreContact

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagrid, datamember, tablename

My problem is outlined here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/314043 Microsoft says: "This behavior is by design." and no workaround is provided.

I need a workaround.

I have a dataset which is populated correctly with the contents of the table name `Sales.StoreContact`.

When I try `DataGridView1.DataMember="Sales.SalesContact"` the IDE throws:

> Argument Exception was unhandled.
> Child list for field Sales cannot be created.

I don't want to rename my tables either.

the dataset contains

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Sales.SalesContact>
    <SalesContactID>1</SalesContactID>  
    <Name>Jimmy&lt;/Name>  
    <ReasonType>Damaged&lt;/ReasonType>  
   <ModifiedDate>2010-01-05T00:00:00+00:00&lt;/ModifiedDate>  
  </Sales.SalesContact>  
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: I used                 .DataSource = dsTableContents.Tables.Item(0)
as I had to use this op in a dynamic context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: If your `DataTable` itself is called "Sales.SalesContact", you could try setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` property directly to the `DataTable` (instead of the `DataSet`):

```
Dim salesContactTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables("Sales.SalesContact")
dataGridView.DataSource = salesContactTable
```

---

So you're saying you have a `DataSet` called "Sales", which contains a table called "SalesContact"?

Did you try setting your `DataGridView.DataSource` property to your "Sales" `DataSet` and `DataGridView.DataMember` to simply "SalesContact"?

Comment: <NewDataSet>  
  <Sales.SalesContact>  
    <SalesContactID>1</SalesContactID>  
    <Name>Jimmy</Name>  
    <ReasonType>Damaged</ReasonType>  
    <ModifiedDate>2010-01-05T00:00:00+00:00</ModifiedDate>  
  </Sales.SalesContact>  
</NewDataSet>

Comment: @user323186: I see. So your table itself is called "Sales.SalesContact"?

Comment: just tried that. unfortunately the same result. Child list for field SalesContact cannot be created.  So to confirm I did it correctly I did:             Dim salesContactTable As DataTable = dsTableContents.Tables("Sales.SalesContact"), then associated datasource to salesContactTable and datamember to SalesContact.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user323186: Sorry for all the failed attempts. But my suggestion was a *bit* different from what you just said; I was suggesting to set the `DataSource` to the table (as you did) **but leave `DataMember` blank**; don't assign it to anything. What happens when you try that?

Comment: Its looking good.  Thank you very much.  Strange tho, as i tried that before with the datasource and it didnt work, but fine when I used the dataTable. Would love to know why. But anywho, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check your spaces. I just ran into the same error and I had a space at the end of the table name. For example, `tablename`  and not `tablename`